# Stored Cache File Name Change

Tags: php, caching, outputcache, cache-control, absolute-path

```
<?php
define('CACHE_PATH', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cachefiles/");
// how long to keep the cache files (hours)
define('CACHE_TIME', 12); 
// return location and name for cache file 
function cache_file() 
{ 
    return CACHE_PATH . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

// display cached file if present and not expired 
function cache_display() 
{ 
    $file = cache_file(); 
    // check that cache file exists and is not too old 
    if(!file_exists($file)) return; 
    if(filemtime($file) < time() - CACHE_TIME * 3600) return; 
    // if so, display cache file and stop processing
    readfile($file);
    exit; 
} 

// write to cache file 
function cache_page($content) 
{ 
    if(false !== ($f = @fopen(cache_file(), 'w'))) { 
        fwrite($f, $content);
        fclose($f); 
    } 
    return $content; 
} 

// execution stops here if valid cache file found
cache_display(); 

// enable output buffering and create cache file 
ob_start('cache_page');
?>
```

This code above creates cache with random name

e.g.

4c556ca729a88177e72946a4c3732f62

a87aef8e1d11cee944a8854ab8377ac6

85f2e557d6b483fc06db804d35e6580f

How can it make it stores cache pages with actual page name, like

home-4c556ca729a88177e72946a4c3732f62

about-a87aef8e1d11cee944a8854ab8377ac6

me-85f2e557d6b483fc06db804d35e6580f

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? All you have to do is modify `cache_file()`

Comment: do you know how the above code works? out of curiosity..

Comment: I will build a description, this once, I suggest in the meantime, read the link in my first comment and SO FAQs on proper questions (More info such as type of links would help)

Comment: I also tried return CACHE_PATH . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); @UnholyRanger

Comment: what kind of links do you use? ex1. `domain.tld/home` ex2. `domain.tld/home.php` ex3. other... do you use mod_rewrite or keep urls as is?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's issue is found in the `cache_file()` method. This method handles the building of the name of the cached file when finding or making a new one.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Will return the whole page and variables (ex. `/index.php?var=1`).

In `cache_file()`, it builds the name by taking an `MD5` hash of the request and building the full path to the new file.

```
CACHE_PATH . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

The OP's request was to modify the request to show home/about/me in the cached file name. This can be done by parsing the URI for the name OR simply using the file's name. I will use no rewire `http://domain.tld/index.php` as an example.

```
basename(__FILE__, ".php"); //gives index on index.php
```

Using this, we then modify

```
CACHE_PATH .basename(__FILE__, ".php") . "-" . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

The following will give

```
../path/to/cache/index-{md5hash}
```